# Spring CSRF invalidates the manual logged-in session

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

I am using spring in my web application. I have a signup form. The user fills up this form, the server creates the user account and programmatically logs in the user. The manual login invalidates the current session and creates a new session containing the user principal.

After this signup the user (authenticated) is redirected to a second form to fill up.
I have activated the CSRF protection in spring.

The problem is that after manually login the user, spring creates a new CSRF to manage the second form. This operation invalidates the current logged in session and creates a new session. As result the user is not sent to the second step but again to the login page.

Is there any way to tell spring to use the current manually created session to set the CSRF? Or some other solution?

UPDATE:

SecurityConfig.java:

```
 http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/platform", "/account/verification", "/account/verification/resend", "/signup/business/details")
            .authenticated()
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage(EnvironmentConfig.getDomain() + "/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/auth/login")
            .successHandler(new AuthSuccessHandler());
```

AuthenticationUtils.java

```
// Create authentication token containing user principal
    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, authorities);

    // Clear current security context and fill with new authentication token
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    // Invalidate current session
    if (request.getSession(false) != null) {
        request.getSession(false).invalidate();
    }

    // Create new session with security context
    request.getSession(true).setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
```

The securityConfig shows the security configuration for spring. The AuthenticatioUtils contains the logic to authenticate a user programmatically. After enabling the CSRF support, the manual login is no more working.

Comment: Can you show us the security configuration in your code?

Comment: Hello, I added the snippets for the security config and the code I use to logs in the user manually. Everything used to work fine, when CSRF was disabled. Now that it is enabled, my session is replaced with a new session that I guess is created because of the CSRF

Comment: I have figured out the problem. The issue is not given by spring and the CSRF support.The server receives a request on localhost but then redirects to the IP address of my machine, so the cookie is not sent back to the server because it is bound to localhost. If I use the IP address of my machine to perform the original request everything goes fine.